# Show a list of Drive files and allow the user to select one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites

I want to create a web app to use in a Google Site. The app would allow the user to select a Spreadsheet in Google Drive and pass the file ID to a script to then use the getByID functions to complete a mail merge.  I have all the code working except the selection of the file.  Is there a way to allow a user to browse to a file from their Google Drive, going up/down the tree, etc. as in a File Open scenario?  We are using Google Apps for Non-profits and will be listing domain files.

Answer (score 2):

You can query for all of the users sheets using DriveApp.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByType(String).

You can build an object you can send to your webapp so the user can select the appropriate sheet.

```
function getAllSpreadsheets(){
     var sheetList = [];
      var allSheets = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
      while(allSheets.hasNext()){
        var sheet = allSheets.next();
        sheetList.push({"name":sheet.getName(), "id":sheet.getId()});
    }
return sheetList;
}
```

On your webapp side you could do something like:

```
<label for="selected-sheet">
      <b>Select spreadsheet</b></label>
     <select id="selected-sheet">
     </select>
<script>
$(function(){
  google.script.run
   .withSuccessHandler(addSheets)
   .withFailureHandler(function(e){alert("Error: "+ e)})
   .getAllSpreadsheets();

function addSheets(options){

var select = $('#selected-sheet');
$.each(options, function (i, item) {
    select.append($('<option>', { 
        value: item.id,
        text : item.name 
    }));
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Picker Dialog for this function. Read our [Opening Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open) documentation.

More on the [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) can be also be found in our documentation.

Comment: Thank you. @dan-mcgrath.  Appears I need to figure out the API keys even if this is all for use in our Domain.  Might explain why some other things are not working as well, such as getting the username. Or use a Service Account.  I think I need a little more research there before getting the code together.  I was hoping there was something a little less involved but will look at the Picker API

Comment: Picker api is the right answer. Only drawback is the user can only pick files she has access.